# Intersex Genetalia

Tags: human-biology, genetics

Hypothetically if someone who is born intersex has both sets of fully functioning genitalia (one male one female) could they potentially self fertilize? And if so would it be possible for any genetic variation to take place?

Comment: Coincidentally, I was just reading about this today on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_hermaphroditism#Human_prevalence).

Comment: Given the lack of observation and evidence, I don't think this question can be sufficiently answered without including a great deal of unsupported speculation. VTC.

Answer (score 2):

Someone born intersex does NOT have "both sets of functioning genitalia". It simply does not happen. That is a common misconception. Nearly every male organ has a female equivalent. The same embryonic tissue for each organ develops as male, female or gets stuck in between. Which parts do what depends on the specific condition. One cannot have a clitoris AND a penis for example because both  come from the same original structure. The only exception are the organs originating from the Mullerian Ducts (female) and Wolffian Ducts (male) but again it is nearly impossible for both of those to develop as fully functional in the same person.

Also, when both an ovary and a testicle develop it is because two embryos joined together forming a composite human with two different sets of DNA, one forming an ovary and the other a testicle. The genitalia would be rather jumbled making fertility as one sex difficult and as both sexes pretty much impossible.